# strange issue with publishing website (the images don't show up after publishing)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, web-hosting, web-deployment

I developed a website in ASP.Net 3.5.  When I compile it with Visual Studio on the HOST Machine, the website shows up correctly!  But when I publish the website to the host machine's website hosting folder, type the navigate to the site in the IE, it shows up this way:

1. the images do not show up
2. fonts are not recognized

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?!

I mean the same Host Machine!  Same IE (version8)!  Compiling it with Visual Studio 2008 on that machine, every thing is fine, but when calling the published site on the same host machine by typing the URL in IE, the images don't show up and the fonts are not recognized.

Comment: Did you create the application within IIS?

Comment: @dbaseman No , I created the website with asp.net and I published It in IIS

Comment: That might be the problem then.  You'll want to go into IIS manager, right click on the virtual path, and `convert to application`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images/fonts not showing up is a sign that your relative paths are off.  One common cause of this is forgetting to creating the IIS application when you deploy.  If you don't create the application, then image paths written like this:

```
~/content/images/img1.jpg
```

will be broken.  (They'll resolve to *mydomain.com/content/images/img1.jpg* instead *mydomain.com/myapplication/content/images/img1.jpg*.)

Another possibility is that your relative paths are written like this:

```
/content/images/img1.jpg
```

This type of link will always be broken if you deploy to any sub-path within a domain.  Ie, if you deploy to *mydomain.com* then the links will be good, but if you deploy to *mydomain.com/myapplication*, then URLs written like the above will resolve incorrectly as *mydomain.com/content/images/img1.jpg*.

Comment: thx alot for your answear , I wrote my images this way <img src="Images/Logo.png" />  how should I write them ? This website runs on a local network and i have an IP address and not a domain name !

Comment: @Karamafrooz so you're loading the site by entering `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/default.aspx`?  Or how?

Comment: @Karamafrooz Hmm... strange.  If you go to *xx.xx.xx.xx/images/logo.png*, does the image show up correctly?

Comment: Yes when I goto xx.xx.xx.xx/IMages/Logo.png thee image does not show up

Comment: @Karamafrooz wow, that's bizarre.  What if you copy `logo.png` to the same folder as `default.aspx`, then surely you can see the image at *xx.xx.xx.xx/logo.png*... right?  If IIS really isn't serving images, then all I can think of is that the MIME type for .png was removed somehow.  Sorry, I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: I pasted the image in root directory and again It did not show up :(

Comment: I tried Logo.jpg and did not work so the problem was not with png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16124/discussion-between-dbaseman-and-karamafrooz)